# Rails 4 - Polymorphic Association - Nested Attributes not showing in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, polymorphic-associations

I am building a login system that has two users, buyer and seller, in Rails 4.0.4.

For auth I am using the Devise gem: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

To create a new buyer I use the route buyer/new. However, the fields for the user do not show in the view. I also using debug to show **@buyer.user** in the view and it has been created.  But when I call **f.fields_for @buyer.user do |u|** the loop is never entered.

Any ideas of why this is? Also, the polymorphic associations seem to be working in the rails console.

**Buyer Controller:**

```
  # GET /buyers/new
  def new
    @buyer = Buyer.new
    @buyer.build_user
  end
```

**Buyer Model**

```
class Buyer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :role
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

**Buyer/new View**

```
<%= form_for(@buyer) do |f| %>
  ....
  <div class="field">
    <%= debug(@buyer.user)  %>
    <% f.fields_for @buyer.user do |u| %>
      <%= u.text_field :email %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

**User Model**

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :role, polymorphic: true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't you have an = on the fields_for? http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper:fields_for

E.G.

```
<%= f.fields_for @buyer.user do |u| %>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have been researching this for over an hour now and finally decided to ask.  I never even noticed that was missing. It makes sense though because Rails was working it's magic in the console. lol

Comment: It worked in the console because that was the return value. However nothing was telling ERB to print the output without that outer =. No problem though, I've had the same issue :D